# PSU - Graphic card combo. Should I get a new PSU, or can I get an adapter?

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, power-supply

I'm trying to connect [this card](https://www.newegg.com/gigabyte-geforce-gtx-1660-super-gv-n166soc-6gd/p/N82E16814932224?Item=N82E16814932224) :

(*GIGABYTE GeForce GTX 1660 SUPER DirectX 12 GV-N166SOC-6GD 6GB 192-Bit GDDR6 PCI Express 3.0 x16 ATX Video Card*)

To my ASUS P8Z77-V LX mobo. The problem is that my 750 watt PSU doesn't have the 8 pin connector for PCI-E. I'm having trouble finding online documenatation on this darn psu, so here is a photo of my PSU's info:

[image]

What should I do to get this graphics card to work? Should I get a new PSU, or is there a way to get this graphics card to work well with an adapter and not setting my house on fire, or any other trick?

Edit: I finally found some specific specifications on my PSU, [this link](http://www.ascendtech.us/ultra-ult-lsp750-750-watt-power-supply_i_pwrsplultlsp750.aspx)

These specs only confirm that I do not have an 8 pin connector for PCI-E, only two 6 pins. So I still need some insight here...

Edit 2: After hours of research and confusing contradictions in comments, I found that the two 6pin to a single 8 pin adapter is okay to use. This is because if a power supply has two 6 pins for PCI-E, it can supply two 75 watt devices. A single 8 pin PCI-E cable supplies 150 watts. This is the same number of watts (150 = 75*2) between the three of them. If anyone has insight otherwise, please let me know, or I will answer my own question with this new-found knowledge.

Comment: You should be submitting an answer instead of providing the solution within the question body itself.  Otherwise, the question will be closed, since you have already answered the question.

Comment: That's what I plan on doing in a few hours Ramhound. I'm just waiting to see if someone has information to prove me wrong first for a few hours. I'm not a hardware expert, so I'd like to wait just a little bit.